# Can I keep my visual studio window arrangement after I RDP?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have all of my windows in Visual Studio arranged as I like them on my multi-monitor system.  When I remote in from home to do some work, the windows are moved around in order to fit to my screens at home.  When I come back to work all the windows are squashed onto one screen and I have to re-arrange them all to where I want them to be.

Is there any way to keep things the correct way when I come in to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I keep my same 4-monitor setup when using Remote Desktop in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/288702/how-do-i-keep-my-same-4-monitor-setup-when-using-remote-desktop-in-windows-7)

Comment: The linked question specifies that all monitors are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio actually has a featured called [Window Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.windowconfigurations.aspx) that would probably help you out.  However, unfortunately, there is no UI in VS to access Window Configuration.  The [StudioShell Add-In](https://studioshell.codeplex.com/) does give you access to them, so you could use it.  In fact, the creator of StudioShell wrote a [blog post](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Access-Window-Configurations-with-StudioShell.aspx) explaining how he did exactly what you want, except with a docking station instead of RDP.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for.  When I have time, I'll try it out and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could set your RDP session to smart sizing & preserve your multi-screen setup remotely…

- edit your .rdp files with notepad and type in the following line:
  smart sizing:i:1

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the window positions is not something that Visual Studio will do for you when you drop into your office chair. It just remembers the positions while you were putting those lines of code together via RDP

I ended up creating a C# application and assume you can do also. Hey! You're a programmer right!?!

Taken from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455741/export-import-visual-studio-settings-from-command-line

```c#
    using EnvDTE; // References C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\envdte.dll
    using System;
    using ConfigurationManager = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;
    
    namespace appResetVisualStudioWindowPositions
    {
        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string fullPathToSettingsFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FullPathToSettingsFile"];
                DTE dte = (DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE"); // version neutral
    
                dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", string.Format("/import:\"{0}\"", fullPathToSettingsFile));
    
                //Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                //Console.ReadKey();
            }    
        }
    }
```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="FullPathToSettingsFile" value="C:\docs\visual studio\Visual Studio - Window Positions (vs2019) for 24 inch.vssettings"/>
      </appSettings>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```